# Setting value for select element is not showing in UI

Tags: java, html, vaadin

I am using vaadin select to display a select menu with states.

```
private Select<States> states = new Select<>();
```

```
states.setLabel("State");
states.setItems(facade.stateService().findAllStates());
states.setItemLabelGenerator(States::getName);
```

```
Optional<States> state = facade.stateService().findByCode(location.getLocationState());
if (state.isPresent()) {
    states.setValue(state.get());    // this is not working
}
```

I am getting the state value and setting it using `states.setValue()` but the select is not displaying the updated state. The method is getting called. How to make select the menu selected? Thanks.

Comment: Does States implement equals/hashCode?

Comment: No, but after the implementation this works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to tell based on the code you have shared. Quite likely the `States` object returned by `location.getLocationState().get()` does not share the same object identity with a value returned by `facade.stateService().findAllStates()`. This can happen even if the properties (such as the "name") of the objects are the same. Typically the answer is to implement the `hashCode` and `equals` methods in the class in a way that identity depends only on the id of the entity.